Passing xmlns:gz attribute from <robot> in URDF straight to <model> in SDF
I need to have the xmlns:gz attribute from my URDF file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="my_robot" xmlns:gz="http://gazebosim.org/schema">
 ...
</robot>

to be passed into the SDF file when converted, like this:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <model name='my_robot' xmlns:gz="http://gazebosim.org/schema">
   ...
  </model>
</sdf>

but when i ran gz sdf -p my_robot.urdf > my_robot.sdf i don't see that attribute in the <model> tag.
Is there a way to pass or add the attribute to the SDF file from the URDF one?
My gz sdf version: 14.5.0
Thank you
